# Optimizing 3d-array algorithm using numpy silces

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

Working on a 3d-numpy array of numbers problem that multiplies the values within by a set weights, sums them, and updates them.

I have a 3d-numpy array "grid" with dimentions (H, W, 3), where I want to multiply in some constant weights to the 3 inner values, then sum them together, and update the array with the sum. I wrote the following python algorithm for this:

```
weights = (0.65, 0.33, 0.07)
for i in range(len(grin)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            sum = 0
            for k in range(3):
                sum += grid[i][j][k] * weights[k]
            grid[i][j] = [sum]
```

This works as intended, and now I would like to optimize the code speed/length by using more numpy methods, such as array slicing to cut away some for-loops.
I am still new to numpy and learning, and was wondering what some ways to do this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty straight forward:

```py
h, w = 20, 40
grid = np.random.random((h, w, 3))
weights = (0.65, 0.33, 0.07)


image = (grid * weights).sum(axis=-1)


# np.allclose(image, image2)
# True
```